# Error executing Python script file through Talend tSystem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, talend

I have a .py file that i am trying to execute through Talend using tSystem module. I am getting below error.

```
Starting job MyJob at 07:06 20/02/2017.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3364
[statistics] connected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Talend POC\NameParsingUSData.py", line 7, in <module>
    from unidecode import unidecode
ImportError: No module named 'unidecode'
[statistics] disconnected
Job MyJob ended at 07:06 20/02/2017. [exit code=0]
```

This is how the job looks like.
[image]

Its strange, because when i double click the .py file, it executes and gives the result successfully. I also tried executing the file through cmd command line in command prompt, outside talend and it runs successfully as well. Not sure what might be causing the error. For reference below is my Python script.

```
import os
from unidecode import unidecode
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.read_csv("H:\\Talend POC\\1M_dummyData.csv")

df1.myvar = df1.myvar.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z., ]",r' ')
df1.myvar = df1.myvar.str.replace('\s+', ' ')
df1.myvar = df1.myvar.str.lstrip(".,' ")
df=df1.as_matrix()

df1.to_csv("H:\\Talend POC\\results_USvalidemail_parse.csv",header=True,index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Note that it successfully imports the first library, error starts from the second library import '`unicode`'

Any help?

Comment: Did you try to do a `pip install unidecode` on your server?

Comment: @ishaan i am doing this in local machine. I installed it already in my machine.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't seem to be using `unidecode` library, remove the import line.

Comment: Why will it not work in the first place? That is what my original question.

Comment: Because this is not a standard python library, so you need to install it separately. Talend is probably using a virtualenv with its own set of libraries, so you need to check documentation for that. But missing library in talend's python path is the reason that this isn't working.

Comment: Not sure how can i install it, as i have already installed it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure how talend sandboxes, but virtualenv is the most common way. You should take a look into how to install python modules on Talend. You script would probably run just fine if you manually do a `python script.py` from a terminal

Comment: never mind, i found the answer myself. I am posting the answer for benefit of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason why it works, but this is what my hack was. I searched for any .py file that exists in the Talend data integration dump and i found only one in the directory

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502\bin
```

I tried installing the library in this directory in the command line.

Firstly i ran the below code in command line to go to the directory.

```
cd /d C:\Users\user\Downloads\TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502\bin
```

Secondly, i installed the `unidecode` library using command `pip install unidecode`

I re-executed the talend job and it executed with success!!

tarting job MyJob at 08:05 20/02/2017.

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3983
[statistics] connected
[statistics] disconnected
Job MyJob ended at 08:05 20/02/2017. [exit code=0]
```